# RF: what are some sources that are transmitting few hundred of watts signal power?

Tags: rf, antenna, cellphone

I am looking for some source (TV broadcasting station, or cellular tower,etc)  that transmit a **few hundred watts** of power. (Just typically please).

Please give me some idea to get me started so I can do a little bit research on my own. (Actual, TV broadcasting station doesn't count because it typically transmitting megawatts, MW).

Comment: hundredth?? or hundreds? dBm or dBW level would help

Comment: @hassan789, ok edited.

Comment: @Renan, my bad, I mean few hundreds Watts

Comment: @Kuku The confusion is that, in English, because you have a vague quantity modifier and a plural unit, you do not pluralize the 'hundreds'. It seems that you mean, "a few hundred watts".

Comment: HF amateur radio transmitters typically transmit hundreds of watts.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amateur_radio#Privileges   It isn't clear to me if you're asking for examples of actual, physical *sources* (transmitters) of RF power or if you're looking for some source of *information* on transmitters of RF power in this range.  Would you please clarify your question?

Comment: Typically RF applications and questions are concerned about a specific RF range (or band). Does that matter?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a [small list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBm) to get you started:

> 80 dBm - 100 kW
>     -- Typical transmission power of FM radio station with 50-kilometre (31 mi) range
>   62 dBm - 1.588 kW
>   -- The maximum legal power output of a U.S. ham radio station.[3]
>   60 dBm - 1 kW
>  -- Typical combined radiated RF power of microwave oven elements
>   50 dBm - 100 W
>  -- Typical thermal radiation emitted by a human body. Typical maximum output RF power from a ham radio HF transceiver